# What is the correct driver for HP Officejet Pro 8710 in CUPS?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

My printer is shrinking the page to half vertically. I've installed a hp officejet pro 8710 on my desktop running ubuntu 16.04. When I get to the page (on CUPS site localhost:631), where I have to choose the make and model of the printer from a drop down menu, the options for hp officejet pro start at 1150c and end at 1175c.

I have checked all of the settings, and they seem to be correct. I think I may have the wrong driver. So my question is: What is the correct driver for HP Officejet Pro 8710 in CUPS?

Thank you all very kindly

Comment: Remove printer, Install HPLIP.

Comment: I originally tried to install HPLIP, but got multiple errors during the hplip.3.17.11run install.

Comment: You wouldn't have such errors had you installed the version available for your Ubuntu release in the offcial repositories, i. e. using Ubuntu Software or APT.

Comment: so HP say the 8710 needs at least 3.16.5 and Ubuntu 16.04 only came with 3.16.3 so the current release 3.17.11 is what one takes

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I am not sure why I got errors when I used the HPLIPs download the first time. So before I ran it again, I used the synaptic package manager to remove any old hp files. then I downloaded the HPLIPS 3.17.11 run from HP website. The I ran the install from the terminal. I ran the test page and it printed the page correctly. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Install `hplip-gui` package with `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` and add your 8710 from here.

According to HP page it [is fully supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I am not sure why I got errors when I used the HPLIPs download the first time. So before I ran it again, I used the synaptic package manager to remove any old hp files. then I downloaded the HPLIPS 3.17.11 run from HP website. The I ran the install from the terminal. I ran the test page and it printed the page correctly. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip. Select distro, download & install.
2. `cd /home/user/Downloads`
3. `sudo chmod +x hplip-3.22.6.run`
4. `./hplip-3.22.6.run`